# Oracle Database Object - Last DDL vs TIMESTAMP

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp, ddl

I am trying to determine which date would be reflective of the time an object was modified on an `Oracle 11g` database.

last_ddl_time or Timestamp

I have read a number of threads but can't find a clear cut answer. If I am understanding correctly, there are certain events that will trigger the last DDL date to change but not the TIMESTAMP?

Could anyone elaborate. I have a beginner level understanding so patience is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is this 'timestamp' attribute you are referring to? LAST_DDL_TIME is the last time the table had a DDL (structure) change applied, but does NOT include DML (data).

Answer (score 6):

Yes - [check out the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-AA6DEF8B-F04F-482A-8440-DBCB18F6C976.htm#REFRN20146).

```
LAST_DDL_TIME  Timestamp for the last modification of the object and dependent objects resulting from a DDL statement (including grants and revokes)
TIMESTAMP      Timestamp for the specification of the object (character data)
```

TIMESTAMP is just for the object itself - so if you create a table, this will only get updated if you alter the columns in the table, or some other property of the table itself.

LAST_DDL_TIME includes any change that affects the object, including changes to dependent objects. So if you add a constraint or a grant to your table, LAST_DDL_TIME will get updated for the table but TIMESTAMP won't.

Give it a try with some different DDL statements.

Comment: Thank you Kfinity! That is very helpful - that being said, If I see a last DDL time of Yesterday - but a Timestamp of 2 weeks ago - is it safe to assume that the object itself was not modified but rather some dependent object?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes